# Want to remove null value from dynamic Pivot table

Tags: sql

I'm running into an issue where the output for my dynamic pivot contains thousands of NULL values that I would like to replace with 0. I am not able to use ISNULL

```sql
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(MAX),@str VARCHAR(MAX);                
SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT Distinct '],[' + Replace(ChargeNAme,'&','AND') 
FROM ##AppChargeDetails    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'   

--SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT Distinct '],[' + ISnull(ChargeNAme,'') 
--FROM ##AppChargeDetails    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'   
   
                   
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ##AppChargeDetails)      
BEGIN                    
 SET @str = 'SELECT * into ##AppChargeAmt FROM ##AppChargeDetails                  
  PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR ChargeName IN ('+@listCol+'))  AS pvt'
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to retag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Global temp tables are an indication that the design of this process has some major problems.

Comment: I'd also suggest you take a step back and provide us with an actual [mre]; that means including sample data in DDL and DML form, along with the result you *expect* for the data you've provided (in a consumable format *not* an image).